# Symfony 4 - Multiple forms in one controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

What is the best practice if I want to use multiple forms in one page/controller?

Right now I have multiple actions and I'm including them in twig, but I don't think this is good solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you actually want different, separate forms in your page, you can create many forms in your controller and pass them to Twig, e.g.:

```
public function mypageAction()
{
    $userForm = $this->createForm(UserForm::class, new User);
    $companyForm = $this->createForm(CompanyForm::class, new Company);
    return $this->render('mypage.html.twig', [
        'userForm' => $userForm,
        'companyForm' => $companyForm,
    ]);
}
```

Of course **handling submissions** will require separate actions, one for each form.